# ERROR ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, mobile

ERROR  ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package.

This happens as I upgrade RN from o.64 to .72

Please help

Answer (score 1):

There might be a package that you are using in which ViewPropTypes are imported from react-native ... maybe try to upgrade all the packages or you will have to check each package individually and import ViewPropTypes from `deprecated-react-native-prop-types` instead of react-native . dont forget to install `deprecated-react-native-prop-types`